# Masking casing/outline of line feature (road) within ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, masking, representation

I need to mask just the black outline/casing of road features in my map. Here is an example below. I do not want to mask the entire road as seen here but instead just the black lines on each side of the road. Also, these road features are a representation file, and I would like to keep them in representation. I know an easy workaround outside of representation files but that is not what I wish to do.

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to create a new representation for the roads, or somehow mask half the symbology of existing representation?  Can you please [edit] your question to show how your representation is set up for the road symbols?